# Im mysql, not getting id

Tags: java, mysql

in our chat application, the following is the case, there is person 'A' who have chat with person 'B' in two cases,1) one-to-one chat and 2) group chat. so in the database records are as follows,

**Table : core**

```
  id   name
   1    A
   2    B
   3    C
```

Table : **Master**

```
  id    core_id 
  1       1
  2       2
```

Table : **recepient**

```
 id    core_id    master_id
  1       1        1 
  2       2        1
  3       1        2
  4       2        2
  5       3        2
```

so in the recepient table, we have 2 entries for Person 'A'. Now the problem is, i want the master_id = 1 form recepient table, in which person 'A' and 'B' are communicated. But there are two entries in recepient table for this. so how to get that id?

Comment: your question is not clear. could u be specific  as what should be your output?

Comment: i want the master_id = 1 from recepient table, where person 'A' has chat with person 'B'

Comment: I can not work out what these tables represent.
I would have expected the users table (userID, userDetails) and chatInstance table (chatInstanceID, [further details,] participatingUserID)

The chatInstance table would have many-to-many relationship with user table.

Then in your 
case 1) [one-to-one chat] you would have two records in chatInstance table:
chatInstanceID1, [further details,] userA
and
chatInstanceID1, [further details,] userB

Comment: @GermannArlington from my table structure it is not possible to retrive the result

Comment: @vishal: are you asking us to do something that you know is impossible???

Comment: @GermannArlington i will explain my table structure, table core : unique each persons id. Table master : chat conversion id, and Table recepient : in this table for that perticular chat who is present, so from the my structure, person 'A' has two chats, i.e two master ids 1 and 2, and in recepient table data is inserted, so from reepient table get the record where master_id = 1 i.e person 'A' has chat with person 'B'

Comment: @vishal - I answered below, was this not helpful? If not, please take some time to clarify your question.

Comment: @DaveRlz the answer given by you is not helpful for me. i will explain my table structure, table core : unique each persons id. Table master : chat conversion id, and Table recepient : in this table for that perticular chat who is present, so from the my structure, person 'A' has two chats, i.e two master ids 1 and 2, and in recepient table data is inserted, so from reepient table get the record where master_id = 1 i.e person 'A' has chat with person 'B'.

Comment: @DaveRlz In the records, for person 'A' i.e coreId = 1, two masterId present i.e 1 & 2, so i the output i want is masterId = 1 from the recepient table in that person 'A' & 'B' have chat. But the problem is, in the recepient table there are 2 entries for coreId 1 & 2, so masterId 1 & 2, so i want masterId = 1 from recepient table. How to get that

Comment: @Vishal - have you actually run my query? It should return one record, the one you are looking for. I can't help you any more than this!

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are asking and your table names do not assist in making this any clearer. However, I suspect you are selecting records from the recipient table based only on the master_id and need to join with the other tables so that you can also include the name in the query.

So with this in mind, try the following (caveat: I haven't tested this, and I work with Oracle not mysql) but:

```
select * 
from core c, master m, recipient r
where c.id = m.core_id
and   c.id = r.core_id
and   m.id = r.master_id
and   c.name = 'A'
```

And before anyone complains that this sql does not follow the latest ANSI standard, it's the way I do it and it works for me!